# How do I effectuate /usr/bin/checkmodule and /usr/bin/semodule_package on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, selinux

Or simulate them? It's for a build step that merely needs to succeed, but I'd like to do real work too. I just don't have enough information about it. This is do with SELinux, right? That exists for Ubuntu too; are there equivalent utilities?

Comment: Close voters: Answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/checkmodule` can be found in the [checkpolicy package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/checkpolicy)

`/usr/sbin/semodule` can be found in the [policycoreutils package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/policycoreutils)

Both of these are in the [universe repository.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Details on the utilization of both of these can be found on their respective man pages.

An overview on implementation can be found [on the wiki.](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Building_a_Basic_Policy)

Comment: I ended up writing a couple of scripts that just answered back exit 0, but yeah, I'd like to put real software in. I just didn't know enough about SELinux in Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully the wiki will get you the experience you desire. If you have a specific question, always feel free to [ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)